# Is it possible to delete Geocaches from a Garmin etrex without plugging it into the computer?

Tags: geocaching, gps

My GPS (Garmin extrex 20) will not connect to my computer anymore (via USB), and therefore I cannot access the GPX folder of the device where Geocaches are saved.

As a solution, I would like to save Geocaches on the SD card and plug that into the GPS device. The problem: there are some Geocaches remaining on the memory of the GPS and I cannot seem to find how to delete those. Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: How have you saved them to the device, are they waypoints?

Comment: I saved them as .gpx files (downloaded from the Geocaching site) into the folder named "GPX" on the Garmin device. I'm not sure if they are handled as waypoints. Deleting all waypoints on the device does not delete them.

Comment: @cobaltduck Thank you. I've looked at this option but apart from sort and renaming options I could not find one to delete them.

Comment: If going to the waypoints manager and deleting every entry manually doesn't work, I fear you're stuck with what's been copied in. The only solution would be to get an electronics expert to try and diagnose/fix the issue. I wonder though, why does it not connect anymore? Did this happen after upgrading to a newer computer OS or is it likely a fault in the unit itself?

Comment: My unit is a 30, not a 20, but I played with it for several minutes this morning and I think you might be right, deleting caches within the unit is not possible.  I probably had mixed it up with my Delorme PN60, which is by far more well-used by me, although that one is a battery eater, it's geocaching features are simpler and more intuitive.  But I still keep both.  (Shrug). Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Yes, If you connect to PC. Here are instructions from Garmin. https://support.garmin.com/en-US/?faq=D42qULRinb5KJpUUyhbj59

Answer (score 1):

This is late - however, potentially useful for others in the future.

Long story short - you can't delete files that have been added to the memory via computer!

All the information, including that found on the official [Garmin instructions online](https://www8.garmin.com/manuals/webhelp/eTrex_10_20x_30x/EN-US/GUID-BBF41890-FB0B-4B45-AE18-E83442B68BA8.html) indicate that this must be done through a computer connection.

However (I can't test this as I don't have a device) it seems that all user data can be deleted by doing a factory reset, which should take the device back to the settings as it was when it came out of the box when you first bought it.

[To do a factory reset](https://www.gpsnation.com/support/gps-factory-reset/garmin-etrex-20-factory-reset.html): **Performed at users own risk!**

1. press and hold the "enter" button
2. press the "power/light" button
3. wait for the "Do you want to delete all user data" message
4. select "Yes"

Note that this will delete all waypoints, etc - anything that you have added to the device since getting it. I think internally stored maps (i.e. OEM supplied) will still be there, but perform at your own risk.

Comment: I think I did this back then but to no avail, the Geocaches were still there.